# Chrome crash with webworkers and createImageBitmap

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, crash, web-worker

I'm currently having an issue when loading images with webworkers. I want to batch load a bunch of images and then do some processing on these images (in my case, convert source image to `ImageBitmap` using `createImageBitmap`). Currently the user has the ability to cancel the request. This causes a crash when trying to terminate the worker if the worker hasn't finished. I've created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/e4wcro0o/18/ that crashes consistently.

The issue lies here:

```
function closeWorker() {
   if (!isClosed) {
    console.log("terminating worker");
    isClosed = true;
    worker.terminate();
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < srcImages.length; i++) {
    loadImageWithWorker(new URL(srcImages[i], window.location).toString()).then(function(img) {
    closeWorker();
    console.log(img);
  });
}
```

This may look a bit funky to call `closeWorker()` on the first resolved promise, but does it mean that the crash is reproducible. I've only test on chrome with  `64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `loadImageWithWorker` You do know that will not wait, and load 23 images that are 7360 by 4912 pixels in size,.. I'm not surprised the browser crashes.  It might be better if you get your worker to work on 1 image at a time.

Comment: @Keith Thanks for the reply. The images load fine under normal workflow (remove closeWorker() and see for yourself). The problem lies when trying to terminate the worker safely

Comment: I still think loading 3 Gigs of images is not ideal.  I think your problem is most likely down to the fact when you call closeworker, you have potentially another 22 async operations pending.  Abruptly terminating a worker in this mode I doubt is ideal.

Comment: @Keith Let's not get too bogged down by the size of images here as this will still crash even when loading just 4 images, but I do agree the problem seems to be terminating a worker when there is still a network request pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across the same issue. I think the cause comes terminating the worker during the createImageBitmap function.

I have modified your JSFiddle with a method of terminating the worker at the earliest chance to avoid a crash.

```
const worker = createWorker(() => {

    const pendingBitmaps = {};
    var pendingKill = false;

    self.addEventListener("message", e => {

        const src = e.data;

        if (src == "KILL") {
            pendingKill = true;
            Promise.all(Object.values(pendingBitmaps)).then(_ => self.postMessage("READY"));
        }

        // not accepting anymore conversions
        if (pendingKill) {
            self.postMessage({src, bitmap: null});
            return;
        }

        pendingBitmaps[src] = fetch(src).then(response => response.blob())
            .then(blob => {
                if (pendingKill) return null;
                return createImageBitmap(blob);
            })
            .then(bitmap => {
                self.postMessage({src,bitmap});
                delete pendingBitmaps[src];
            })
    })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wrf1sLbx/16/